# Assign a value of one key to another key in if statement within for loop Python

Tags: python, dictionary, for-loop, if-statement

I have a list of dictionaries in Python. I loop through every dictionary and check if the given key exists. If it does exist I check if the value of this key is empty, if it's empty then I need to save another key's value in that empty key. Can't figure out how to assign a value from one key to another...

My data looks like this:

`my_dicts = [{"Id": "123", "Campaign_Date": "2020-06-30", "Another_Date": "2020-07-01"}, {"Id": "125", "Campaign_Date": "", "Another_Date": "2020-07-01"}]`

The output should like this:

`my_dicts = [{"Id": "123", "Campaign_Date": "2020-06-30", "Another_Date": "2020-07-01"}, {"Id": "125", "Campaign_Date": "2020-07-01", "Another_Date": "2020-07-01"}]`

I have tried the following:

```
for my_dict in my_dicts:
    for key in my_dict.items():
        campaign_key = 'Campaign_Date'
        if key == campaign_key:
            if value == "":
                value = value["Another_Date"] 
        else:
            continue
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just in case if you do not want wish to update original dictionary and at same time make necessary correction into new dictionary.

```
import copy
#my_dicts = [{"Id": "123", "Campaign_Date": "2020-06-30", "Another_Date": "2020-07-01"}, {"Id": "125", "Campaign_Date": "", "Another_Date": "2020-07-01"}]
# New input
my_dicts = [{"Id": "123", "Campaign_Date": "2020-06-30", "Another_Date": "2020-07-01"}, {"Id": "125", "Campaign_Date": "", "Another_Date": "2020-07-01"}, {"Id": "126", "Another_Date": "2020-07-01"}]

my_new_list = copy.deepcopy(my_dicts)

campaign_key = 'Campaign_Date'
for index, my_dict in enumerate(my_new_list):
    # check if "campaign_key" key exists
    if campaign_key in my_dict.keys():
        # Check for empty or null value for key "campaign_key"
        if my_dict[campaign_key] in ["", None]:
            my_dict['Campaign_Date'] = my_dict["Another_Date"]
    else:
        # if key "campaign_key" doesn't exist delete that item from list
        my_new_list.pop(index)

print(my_dicts)
print(my_new_list)
expected_output = [{'Id': '123', 'Campaign_Date': '2020-06-30', 'Another_Date': '2020-07-01'}, {'Id': '125', 'Campaign_Date': '2020-07-01', 'Another_Date': '2020-07-01'}]
if my_new_list == expected_output:
    print("Success")
```

Output:

```
[{'Id': '123', 'Campaign_Date': '2020-06-30', 'Another_Date': '2020-07-01'}, {'Id': '125', 'Campaign_Date': '', 'Another_Date': '2020-07-01'}, {'Id': '126', 'Another_Date': '2020-07-01'}]
[{'Id': '123', 'Campaign_Date': '2020-06-30', 'Another_Date': '2020-07-01'}, {'Id': '125', 'Campaign_Date': '2020-07-01', 'Another_Date': '2020-07-01'}]
Success
```

Comment: Thank you, I also need to check if the `campaign_date` key exists. If it doesn't exist, I want my new_dict not to return it. Only to return the dicts that have `campaign_date` as a key with well some modifications based on the value of that key.

Comment: Not quite. If you rewrite my_dicts to be my_dicts = [{"Id": "123", "Campaign_Date": "2020-06-30", "Another_Date": "2020-07-01"}, {"Id": "125", "Campaign_Date": "", "Another_Date": "2020-07-01"}, {"Id": "126", "Another_Date": "2020-07-01"}]
So the third dict doesn't have the key `Campaign_Date` I want my new dict to return: [{'Id': '123', 'Campaign_Date': '2020-06-30', 'Another_Date': '2020-07-01'}, {'Id': '125', 'Campaign_Date': '2020-07-01', 'Another_Date': '2020-07-01'}

Comment: I have updated code to match your requirements. Can you please verify now ? It now checks for key if the key(`campaign_date `) exist it does update for null/empty values and if key(`campaign_date `)  doesn't exist it deletes that dictionary from the list.

Comment: Perfect! That does exactly what I need. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

```
for my_dict in my_dicts:
    for key in my_dict.items():
        campaign_key = 'Campaign_Date'
        if key == campaign_key:
            if value = "":
                my_dict['Campaign_Date'] = my_dict["Another_Date"] 
        else:
            continue
```

Comment: Almost! You will still never find the missing key, as `my_dict.items()` returns a (key, value) pair. But I guess that might be a typo, since you are using `value` further down? Also, you never update your original dict, only the value used right now.

Comment: Thank you, I have updated the code and updating the original dict.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if it's in the code you're running but there is a bug in the code you gave.

```py
for my_dict in my_dicts:
    for key in my_dict.items():
        campaign_key = 'Campaign_Date'
        if key == campaign_key:
            if value = "": # This should be == otherwise you're assigning value to ""
                value = value["Another_Date"] # value["Another_Date"] Doesn't exist
                # Also this won't put the value into the dictionary
        else:
            continue
```

```py
for my_dict in my_dicts:
    for key, value in my_dict.items():
        if key == 'Campaign_Date' and value == "":
           value = my_dict["Another_Date"]
```

Please note that this will not update your dictionary. To do that replace `value = my_dict["Another_Date"]` with `my_dict.update({'Campaign_Date':my_dict["Another_Date"]})`

Comment: Thank you, `if value = ""` is a bug, I have edited the question. Also, you version of the code looks cleaner, however, if my_dict doesn't have the Campaign_Date key it has to skip the dict altogether and move on to loop through the next dictionary. Which after testing doesn't seem to work as it returns all the data, even the dict that doesn't have campaign_date :/  I guess I have to create another list of dictionaries and append